# Solr suggester returning terms from deleted documents

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a SolrCloud setup and I'm testing the suggestion component. I have several hundred documents in the index. I did not want some of the documents in the index because they contain gibberish (they were binary files that got improperly converted to text). I've removed them from the index, but the gibberish words from them are still showing up in the suggestions.

My suggest configuration looks like this:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">fuzzySuggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">HighFrequencyDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="storeDir">suggester_fuzzy_dir</str>
        <str name="field">dictionary_text</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">phrase_suggest</str>
        <str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str>
        <float name="threshold">0.001</float>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="suggest">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.dictionary">fuzzySuggester</str>
        <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">5</str>
        <str name="suggest.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Note that `buildOnCommit` is set to `true`. I also tried to remove them using a `/suggest` query with the `suggest.build=true` parameter, but that had no effect.

Is there something else required to remove terms from the dictionary?

Comment: Are you sure the deleted docs are correctly expunged from the index ? Try to match these gibberish words right in solr analysis interface to see whether this is coming from the index or the dictionary not being rebuilt

Answer (score 1):

Despite using `expungeDeletes=true` in the update, the deleted documents were still hanging around. Optimizing removed them and appears to have removed all the gibberish terms from suggestions.